# PyQt4 Signals and Slots in isomorfic class

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Given an isomorphic class, let's say a `GraphNode`, which should emit signals and receive signals in slots which have as parameters objects of the class itself, how to properly declare this with the new style signals and slots mechanism?

One workaround for signals I've found was to declare it after the class definition has been declared:

```
class GraphNode(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, title, x, y, width, height, parent=None):
        super(GraphNode, self).__init__(parent)

GraphNode.onCollisionDetected = pyqtSignal(GraphNode, list)
```

but this doesn't look nice (at least to me).

How to declare

- signals
- slots

in such isomorphic classes with the new style of declaration in PyQt4 and Python3, preferably inside the class, not afterwards?

Comment: Note that `QGraphicsItem` is not a `QObject` and cannot have signals or slots. Use `QGraphicsObject` instead.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov Thanks, this explains a lot.